# Google Analytics - GTag.js: Some non-custom not reported in Analytics reports

Tags: google-analytics, gtag.js

I set up Google Analytics on my site to track events. However, some [default events](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gtagjs/events), i.e. *purchase*, and exception events do not appear in my Analytics reports. All my custom events appear in the reports as expected. The *begin_checkout* default event also appears. This inconsistent behavior has me confused.

I can work around this problem by exclusively using custom events, but I don't think I should have to as I'm simply following the documentation. See below for my exception event.

```
  gtag('event', 'exception', {
    'description': errorStringDefinedEarlier,
    'fatal': false
  });
```